# Why linux-based operating systems are called distributions?

Tags: linux, terminology

I wonder why do we call the different Linux-based operating systems (Debian, Fedora, Arch, ...) "distributions".

Comment: Do you have any idea or thoughts about this yourself?

Comment: No, that's the point of the question. There would certainly be some people that know the history of that terminology. Maybe it is because they handle the distributions of the programs and libraries, but that's just a rough guess.

Comment: It is just normal English usage. Santa Claus distributes Christmas presents. "Gives" cam be one-to-one.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant well, I'm not calling the gifts I received as "distributions". A distribution is not a product of a giving. Linux distribution is also the term to refer to the actual OS running on your computer, not just the organism that manage it and "gives" it to the people.

Comment: @NicolasDusart "A distribution is not a product of a giving" ... No, it can be. [Merriam-Webster's definition 3 a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distribution): "something distributed"

Comment: If you are after a bit of history and background then take a look over [here - Rebel Code](https://archive.org/details/rebelcodeinsides00mood)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term likely comes from BSD -  [Berkeley Software *Distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution).

> BSD stands for “Berkeley Software Distribution”. It is the name of
>   distributions of source code from the University of California,
>   Berkeley, which were originally extensions to AT&T's Research UNIX®
>   operating system.
>
> — 1. What is BSD? from [*Explaining BSD*](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/explaining-bsd/article.html#what-is-bsd)

(You should read the rest of that page as well.)

Also:

> #### Early Distributions
>
> Meanwhile, interest in the error recovery work in the Pascal compiler
>   brought in requests for copies of the system. Early in 1977, Joy put
>   together the "Berkeley Software Distribution." This first distribution
>   included the Pascal system, and, in an obscure subdirectory of the
>   Pascal source, the editor ex. Over the next year, Joy, acting in the
>   capacity of distribution secretary, sent out about thirty free copies
>   of the system.
>
> —  Twenty Years of Berkeley Unix: From AT&T-Owned to Freely Redistributable
>   by Marshall Kirk McKusic, from 
>   [Open Sources: Voices from the Open Source Revolution, 1st Edition January 1999](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/opensources/book/kirkmck.html)